# Deleting rows based on character length

Tags: excel, vba

trying to delete rows with cells with fewer than 2 characters.  range("A1") line is highlighted and i have no idea why.
i can run it without the line and for some reason it deletes everything.
any advice greatly appreciated.  here's the code:

```vb
Option Explicit
    
    Sub way()
    
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.activate
    
    For Each cell In Selection
    
        If Len(cell) < 2 Then Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    
    Next cell
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean you can run it without the line? without which line?

Comment: the range("A1") line.

Comment: george, how did you put the code in a grey box? thanks

Comment: it is simple the quotation marks font is wrong. Fix the left one. that is a different character.

Comment: The quotation mark `“` before `A1"` should be `"`

Comment: that helped, thx, but it still deletes everything rather than just cells with less than 2 characters like its supposed to

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
Sub mysub()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Double
    Dim rcount as Double
    Dim mybool As Boolean

    Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    i = 1
    mybool = False

    Do
        rcount = r.Rows.count
        For j = 1 To r.Columns.count
            If Len(Cells(i, j).Value) < 2 Then
                Rows(i).Delete
                If rcount = 1 then Exit Sub
                mybool = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If mybool = False Then i = i + 1
        mybool = False
    Loop While i <= rcount

End Sub
```

Edit: just to elaborate on why I provided a new code alltogether here - the logic behind the original code is actually flawed anyway.

Consider for instance what happens if you range involves the following consecutive rows

```
     A     B     C      D     E
 1   ee    e     eee    ee    eee
 2   f     fff   fff    ff    ff
```

Your code will explore each cell row by row top to bottom, from left to right. So in this example:

- when reaching B1, it will delete row 1, and row 2 will be moved to row 1
- from there, your loop will pick up from cell C1 - not A1. In other words, it will miss out on exploring the value of cell A1 which should qualify the row for deletion

Comment: It initially didn't occur to me that the range r wouldn't compare to "Nothing" in instances where all the lines making up the range end up deleted. This is what is causing the issue you are aluding to. Apologies about that. I now have made a couple adjustements to accommodate, should be all fine

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a slow loop by using `AutoFilter`

This code

1. Works out the size of the current region from A1
2. In the next column adds an array formula checking the length of all cells in each row, `=MIN(LEN(A1:C1))<2`
3. AutoFilter deletes the `True` results

[image]

*code*

```
Sub NoLoops()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set rng2 = Range(Cells(1, rng1.Columns.Count + 1), Cells(rng1.Rows.Count, rng1.Columns.Count + 1))
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
With rng2
    .Formula = "=MIN(LEN(RC[-" & rng1.Columns.Count & "]:RC[-1]))<2"
    .FormulaArray = .FormulaR1C1
    .Value = .Value
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="TRUE"
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub way()

Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    If Len(Cell) < 2 Then Cell.EntireRow.Delete
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@IAmDranged is correct in that when you are deleting a row, the next row will move up and become the current row. The `Next cell` line will then pass over this row and move to the next row without checking to see if any Cells are less than 2 characters in length.

Another method for this would be to leave the `Delete` method until after the Cells with fewer than 2 characters have been found:

```
Sub way()

Dim cell As Range
Dim deleteRange As Range 'This will be used to store the Cells found

Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Activate

For Each cell In Selection

    If Len(cell) < 2 Then

        If deleteRange Is Nothing Then
            ' If this is the first cell found, then Set deleteRange to this cell
            Set deleteRange = cell
        Else
            ' Any cells found after the first, we can use the
            ' Union method to add it to the deleteRange
            Set deleteRange = Application.Union(cell, deleteRange)
        End If

    End If

Next cell

' Once all cells have been found, then Delete
deleteRange.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.  why cant i use this code with a left() function though, deleting things that start with a certain string?  this is what i tried:
<p>

Sub DeleteRow()

Dim deleteRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim please As String
Set please = cell.Value

Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Activate
For Each cell In Selection
    If Left(please, 5) = "Sorry" Then
        If deleteRange Is Nothing Then
            Set deleteRange = cell
        Else
            Set deleteRange = Application.Union(cell, deleteRange)
        End If
    End If
Next cell

deleteRange.delete

End Sub
</p>

Comment: `please` is a String so you don't need the `Set` statement in the `Set please = cell.Value` line. Try changing the `If Len(cell) < 2 Then` line of the above code to `If Left(cell) = "Sorry"` and see if this works for you.